Refactor multiple public classes in a folder/namespace to internal classes
Imagine 10 public classes in a folder/namespace. I want to make all of them internal. Any way to do this using Rider without modifying each file manually?

I don't know Rider at all. But VS and others do let you target open files. Search/replace -> target all open files. search phrase of "public class" ?

In Visual studio, click ctrl+shift+h (or just go to Edit->Find and Replace->Replace in Files, choose the specific directory, and replace public class with internal class.

There is no dedicated refactoring for many classes. You either open file by file and refactor it via Alt + Enter or as already pointed out by the other via textual replacement
